# Pandas 1.1.0 groupby dropna=False argument unexpected behaviour with rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas 1.1.0, dropna=False is introduced as argument in groupby to allow for NA in group keys. Example of normal behaviour below:

```
data = {'group':['g1', 'g1', 'g1', np.nan, 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', np.nan], 
                    'A':[3, 1, 8, 2, 6, -1, 0, 13, -4, 0, 1], 
                    'B':[5, 2, 3, 7, 11, -1, 4,-1, 1, 0, 2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby('group',dropna=False)['A'].mean()

#### Output
group
g1     3.40
g2     2.25
NaN    1.50
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

However, we do not see this behaviour with rolling groupby. NA is not added to group key.

```
df.groupby('group',dropna=False)['A'].rolling(1,min_periods=1).mean()

#### Output
group   
g1     0     3.0
       1     1.0
       2     8.0
       4     6.0
       5    -1.0
g2     6     0.0
       7    13.0
       8    -4.0
       9     0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Is this expected or is there an alternative formulation for this scenario?

Comment: This looks like a bug, you should open a ticket on GitHub for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily override it with "NaN"

```
data = {'group':['g1', 'g1', 'g1', np.nan, 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', np.nan], 
                    'A':[3, 1, 8, 2, 6, -1, 0, 13, -4, 0, 1], 
                    'B':[5, 2, 3, 7, 11, -1, 4,-1, 1, 0, 2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.assign(group=lambda dfa: dfa.group.fillna("NaN"))\
    .groupby('group')['A'].rolling(1,min_periods=1).mean()
```

**output**

```
group    
NaN    3      2.0
       10     1.0
g1     0      3.0
       1      1.0
       2      8.0
       4      6.0
       5     -1.0
g2     6      0.0
       7     13.0
       8     -4.0
       9      0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```